# Copy All Elements inside the Node but not the node tag in XML using java

Tags: java, xml

I want to append the elements inside  to another xml with  tag. I dont want to copy  tag.

I am doing the following but it copies the node name () too.

```
NodeList itemsNodeList = inputDoc.getElementsByTagName("Sequence");

            for (int i = 0; i < itemsNodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node copiedNode = resultDoc.importNode(itemsNodeList.item(i), true);
                resultRatingsBodyNode.appendChild(copiedNode);
            }
```

These are the xmls I want to copy from (everything inside sequence tag)

xml1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<processes>
    <process>
        <body name="main">
            <sequence>
                <receive name="Receive1" createInstance="yes" />
                <assign name="Assign1" />
                <invoke name="Invoke1" />
                <style>
                    <Font>someFont</Font>
                </style>
                <assign name="Assign2" />
                <reply name="Reply1" />
            </sequence>
        </body>
    </process>
</processes>
```

xml2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<processes>
    <process>
        <body name="main">
            <sequence>
                <receive name="Receive1" createInstance="yes" />
                <assign name="Assign2" />
                <invoke name="Invoke2" />
                <style>
                    <Font>someFont1</Font>
                </style>
                <assign name="Assign3" />
                <reply name="Reply2" />
            </sequence>
        </body>
    </process>
</processes>
```

This is the xml I want to copy to (inside sequence tag>

blank.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<processes>
    <process>
        <body name="main">
            <sequence>              
            </sequence>
        </body>
    </process>
</processes>
```

This is what I am expecting
Result.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<processes>
    <process>
        <body name="main">
            <sequence>
                <receive name="Receive1" createInstance="yes" />
                <assign name="Assign1" />
                <invoke name="Invoke1" />
                <style>
                    <Font>someFont</Font>
                </style>
                <assign name="Assign2" />
                <reply name="Reply1" />
                <receive name="Receive2" createInstance="yes" />
                <assign name="Assign2" />
                <invoke name="Invoke2" />
                <style>
                    <Font>someFont1</Font>
                </style>
                <assign name="Assign3" />
                <reply name="Reply2" />
            </sequence>
        </body>
    </process>
</processes>
```

**UPDATE**
If I have have follwing blank.xml how do I delete the elements in the sequence node before copying elements into it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<processes>
    <process>
        <body name="main">
            <sequence> 
               <delete>Delete everthing between sequence tag before copying</delete>
            </sequence>
        </body>
    </process>
</processes>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I am getting the following. I think it is deleting everything inside the  node before copying.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<processes>
    <process>
        <body name="main">
            <sequence>
                <receive name="Receive2" createInstance="yes" />
                <assign name="Assign2" />
                <invoke name="Invoke2" />
                <style>
                    <Font>someFont1</Font>
                </style>
                <assign name="Assign3" />
                <reply name="Reply2" />
            </sequence>
        </body>
    </process>
</processes>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process only the childNodes.

```java
NodeList itemsNodeList = inputDoc.getElementsByTagName("sequence");
Node resultSequence= resultDoc.getElementsByTagName("sequence").item(0);

NodeList resultChildren=resultSequence.getChildNodes();
for(int i=0;i<resultChildren.getLength();i++) {
    resultSequence.removeChild(resultChildren.item(i));
}

for (int i = 0; i < itemsNodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    NodeList children=itemsNodeList.item(i).getChildNodes();
    for(int j=0;j<children.getLength();j++) {
        Node copiedNode = resultDoc.importNode(children.item(j), true);
        resultSequence.appendChild(copiedNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sascha, it is exactly what I needed. What do I need to do to clear out and check if the <sequence> node is empty before copying elements into it? I have added update section in my question above. Thank you again !!

Comment: You "simply" remove the children. I added the code for this.

Comment: You are awesome Sascha.. !!

Comment: Sascha, your code is working but it is deleting the contents inside <Sequence> node, I imported from xml1.xml

Comment: Yes, if you place the delete directly before the insert, it will do that. Just place it before all inserts, probably outside of the loop or method call they're in.